# WPML icl_register_string() throws fatal error but works

Tags: translation, plugin-wpml

I'm helping someone with a custom plugin and they need it to be WPML compatible. Using the method from WPML I was able to register a string in WPML and output it on the other end. However, when the plugin was initially activated I got a **Call to undefined function icl_register_string()** error. It worked, but threw a fatal error. Any idea why this could be? Source: http://wpml.org/documentation/support/translation-for-texts-by-other-plugins-and-themes/

Here's my code:

```
//Register Settings with WPML
icl_register_string( 'Match Previous Order' , 'match_order', 'Do you want these items to match a previous order from Direct Linen? If yes, use "Additional Notes" to explain.' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use the wpml functions as following: (the HowTo linked by you actually suggests this :-)

```
if( function_exists('icl_register_string') ) { icl_register_string( 'Match Previous Order' , 'match_order', 'Do you want these items to match a previous order from Direct Linen? If yes, use "Additional Notes" to explain.' ); }
```

This will ensure that you won't get any errors in case WPML doesn't exist in a Wordpress Installation or WPML wasn't fully loaded before your code is run (this is the case when your plugin is activated).